# Java - Issues with MouseListener Coordinates

Tags: java, mouselistener

This is a sample of a larger program used to draw rectangles. A rectangle object is drawn on screen already. what I am attempting to do with the mousedPressed object is get the coordinates of the mouse, and compare it with that of the rectangle's (which are initially set to (100, 100, 200, 200)). The mouseDragged event should take the coordinates obtained in the mousePressed section and run code with them; however, it seems that no matter what, the coordinates are always 0 in the mouseDragged event. I added test code (as marked) to each event to simply change the color of the square when the coordinates are at a certain point. The test code in mousedPressed works just fine, but the test code in mouseDragged can never run. I have tried with many, many different values, and determined that the coordinates will always equal 0 in the mouseDragged event. If someone could help me understand why the int values are not being passed, despite referencing the same variable, I would appreciate it.

```
public class PointListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
        private int mousex, mousey;
        //in case that a user presses using a mouse,
        //record the point where it was pressed.
        public void mousePressed (MouseEvent event) {
            //getPoint() returns a Point object containing the x & y-coordinates
            currentPoint = event.getPoint();
            mousex = event.getPoint().x;
            mousey = event.getPoint().y;
            repaint();
            if (mousex > 250) {
                currentColor = Color.GREEN;
                repaint();
            } //The test, which can easily be triggered as expected
        }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            if (95 < mousex && mousex < 105) {
                currentColor = Color.BLUE;
                repaint();
            }
            if (mousex > 150) {
                currentColor = Color.RED;
                repaint();
            } // The test, which can never be triggered
        } //mouseDragged()
    } //PointListener
```

Comment: Have you run in your IDE debugger and set a breakpoint in `mouseDragged()` to examine the event object?

Comment: The IDE I use (TextPad 8) doesn't support such luxuries, unfortunately, so I have not. I wonder what that would do, however?

Comment: You're not using the `event`in mouseDragged; you're just using the coordinates saved in `mousePressed`

Comment: Aye, it seems moving the entire code from mousePressed to mouseDragged solves the issue, though I'm still not positive as to why simply using the coordinates wouldn't work

Comment: Based on my testing, it seems to work okay - however, remember, `mousePressed` won't be called in the event of a drag operation, on `mouseClicked`. It would also be very helpful if your provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: *"why simply using the coordinates wouldn't work"* because they are assigned a value in a point of time and won't be updated till `mousePressed` is called again?

Comment: By limiting yourself to Textpad (an editor, not an IDE) you are doing the equivalent of trying to do serious precision carpentry with stone tools.  Eclipse is completely free and will increase your productivity by an order of magnitude.

Comment: The issue there is that if I madly clicked on a location that would set the x-coordinate to, say, 200, then dragged a few pixels in any direction, it still would not switch the color to Red as it should. Using code that said `if (mousex == 0)` would always work, no matter where I pressed.